# How can I check unchange row value in dataframe(by grouping ID)

Tags: r

how can i check unchanged row dynamically from data frame.(by grouping ID)

my data frame.

```
    ID       NAME           GENDER             AGE
     1       muthu          male               20
     1       MUTHU          MALE               20
     2       NA             male               28
     3       jake           male               30
     3       jake           male               31
     4       jhon           male               21
     4      \n\rjhon\n\r    \n\male\n\r        21 
     5        NA             NA                NA 
     5        NA             NA                NA
```

expected result will be.

```
Unchanged ID
         1
         2
         4
         5
```

dput data ,

```
structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5), NAME = structure(c(4L, 
5L, NA, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, NA, NA), .Label = c("\\n\\rjhon\\n\\r", 
"jake", "jhon", "muthu", "MUTHU"), class = "factor"), GENDER = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, NA, NA), .Label = c("\\n\\male\\n\\r", 
"male", "MALE"), class = "factor"), AGE = c(20, 20, 28, 30, 31, 
21, 21, NA, NA)), .Names = c("ID", "NAME", "GENDER", "AGE"), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @ akrun,i need to return unchanged row value (ID).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option using `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'ID', remove any `\n` or `\r` after converting it to 'lower', find the number of unique elements (`uniqueN`), check whether it is equal to 1, then `Reduce` it back to a single logical column using `&`, and subset the 'ID' based on the logical column ('V1')

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Reduce(`&`, lapply(.SD, function(x) 
    uniqueN(gsub("([\\]+)(n|r)|[\\]+", "", tolower(x)))==1)) , ID][(V1), .(ID)]
#   ID
#1:  1
#2:  2
#3:  4
#4:  5
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R idea. We clean the names from `\\n` and `\\r` and convert them `tolower`. After that the unchanged rows are the one with duplicates. The second condition, is for the group to have only one entry which we handle with `ave`.

```
c(df$ID[duplicated(sapply(df, function(i) tolower(gsub('[\\]n|[\\r]', '', i))))], 
  df$ID[with(df, ave(ID, ID, FUN = length)) == 1])

#[1] 1 4 5 2
```